# Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2. in phone gap project (android studio)?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins

I am new in phone gap.integrated facebook plugin in my project .after running error showing

```
`Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.'
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.1.2/bolts-android-1.1.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.1.2/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.1.2/bolts-android-1.1.2.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.1.2/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:FacebookLib:3.21.1

pls help me.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'


}
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
    compile project(subproject)
}
compile files('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib/libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
}

android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + getVersionCodeFromManifest() + "0")
}

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

if (multiarch || System.env.BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS) {
    productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", ""
            }
        }
        all {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "all", ""
            }
        }
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

def getVersionCodeFromManifest() {
def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
matcher.find()
return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def getProjectList() {
def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
def projects = []
while (matcher.find()) {
  projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
}
return projects
}
```

Comment: Please paste your `build.gradle` file. It looks like you're missing a remote repository declaration.

Comment: pls check ..addeed build.gradle

Answer (score 5):

Try it may be helpful.

Failed to resolve : `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'`

**Go to menu :** File -> Settings - > Build, Execution, Deployment - > Build Tools -> Gradle

In - Project-level-setting

Checked or select- User default gradle wrapper(recommended)

and

In - Global Gradle Setting

Disable offline Work

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the repositories declaration in your script. What you do have is the repositories in `buildscript` closure, that configures the build itself (e.g. to find the Android plugin needed for the build to run), but you don't have a repositories declaration that will bring the dependencies your classes need.
Please add

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
```

That should do the trick.